# Updating two drop down boxes via Ajax

Tags: jquery, bind, onchange, eventtrigger

I have two drop down boxes that update via Ajax, both work fine when used manually.

a user clicks on first drop down and selects an item that makes an Ajax call and updates the second drop down box. When user clicks second drop down Ajax response updates form.

Now my problem:
I want to be able to send user to that form with a URL and pass two variables so that form checks the variables and updates both drop downs automatically. I am able to update first drop down with out any problems and also trigger the change event. But for some reason second drop down box value does not update.

Following is snippet of code I have:

```
jQuery('#jform_make').val('<?php echo $make; ?>');
jQuery('#jform_make').trigger('change', function() {
    console.log("state changed");
    jQuery('#jform_service').val('<?php echo $service; ?>');
    jQuery('#jform_service').change();
});
//jQuery('#jform_make').change( function(){
jQuery('#jform_make').bind('change', function() {
    console.log("state changed");
});
```

This does not even log anything in Console.

Update:

```
jQuery('#jform_make').val('<?php echo $make; ?>').change();
jQuery('#jform_make').change(function(event) {
    console.log(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no code here to update a second drop down. How about providing a **complete** [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: more code added, I dont see anything in console log when first drop down is updated and it also updates the second drop down.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dU7kz/1/

**HTML:**

```
<select id="dd1" class="dropdown"></select>
<select id="dd2" class="dropdown"></select>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#dd1').append('<option value="1">My option 1</option>');
$('#dd1').append('<option value="2">My option 2</option>');
$('#dd1').append('<option value="3">My option 3</option>');
$('#dd1').append('<option value="4">My option 4</option>');
$('#dd1').append('<option value="5">My option 5</option>');
$('#dd1').val('3');

$('#dd2').append('<option value="6">My option 6</option>');
$('#dd2').append('<option value="7">My option 7</option>');
$('#dd2').val('7');

$('.dropdown').change(function(event) {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: still not working. I have updated code above, please note that first drop down DOES NOT change with user click, it changes when AJAX response comes back.

Comment: I will try to create a fiddle.